# Re-run the auto DHCP configuration

Tags: server, dhcp

I need to re-run the network configuration, as everything has changed. How can I re-run the auto-configuration?

This is on 12.04 Server

Answer (score 3):

`sudo dhclient -r` should release the current IP configuration, and `sudo dhclient` should get a new ip address after that. I'd personally prefer to run `ifup ethX` then `ifdown ethX` where ethX is the devicename to disconnect and reconnect the network, in case there's anything else that needs resetting